# MVC architecture and weakly typed languages (for instance PHP) Is model unnecessary?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, model, weakly-typed

Shouldn't models just describe data that will be passed from a controller to a view? Doesn't that make models unnecessary in weakly typed languages? In PHP, they are doing DB work in models, but isn't that wrong? As I see it, models are just unnecessary in weakly typed languages...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some misconceptions about the term model. Microsoft's MVC3 framework has the concept of a view-model, which is simply the data you use to render your views. This isn't however what the M stands for exactly in MVC. The model includes your business entities. We have thin controllers and fat models, but very thin view models. Our controllers make calls to services that perform business logic, and the controllers never do this logic themselves. We then translate our business entities (our data models) and convert them into a lightweight view model, which can be used for rendering a view.

So to answer your question

> Shouldn't model just describe data that will be passed from controller to view?

Then perhaps what you are really asking is aren't view-models unnecessary? I'm not sure why you think this. View model + view makes the result. In PHP it can be helpful to define a class with easily accessible properties on it. This is just sensible for clarifying your expectations and prevents you from calling methods with hideously long sets or arguments. In JavaScript there is no need to define a view model as such, you just push the properties onto a new object and pass it along with your view to your view rendering logic. This is more a reflection of the OO pattern these languages use and not the fact that they are weakly typed.

If you are asking if model is unnecessary, then you have missed the purpose of the MVC architecture. A big part of MVC is that you separate your concerns. Why apply any architecture to your code? I am sure you can find a better explanation of the motivation behind MVC than I can give you.

Answer (score 1):

A model is a useful conceptual tool, even if it's not strictly necessary in PHP to separate it from the DB code e.g. you can have a data object associated with each table that encapsulates some business logic, or define a set of business entities that aggregate the data across tables into domain-specific objects that the controllers can then use, or just have one monster DB object that has all the access functions and returns the entities. This has definite advantages over having DB code directly in use by the controllers:

- If you are defining complex data structures that run across DB tables, you don't want to do that in controller code due to the risk of duplication - far better to have a single definition that enforces consistency across the system. Although this can introduce dependencies, having one function/object that defines that data makes it easy to find out where the data is used so you can fix things.
- Third party maintenance is far easier if there's one place to go to where all the data structure definitions are found.
- It makes unit testing easier if you can swap out the whole model or parts of it and replace it with mock object(s) that will provide test data
- It makes controllers lighter and therefore more readable and maintainable

So you could argue that it's not necessary, but it helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I've always seen models as a tool to provide data. That means that your controller doesn't ever have to worry about the data source, and if you want to switch from using a database to XML files then you only have to swap out your model.

Answer (score 0):

So long as you have some data provider abstraction. Some Models will do low level validation (tightly coupled to the storage engine - null checks etc) but the controller "should" do all of the business logic/validation.

I personally have a thin struct like class that is mapped to each table (all implementing IDataStruct). This struct, or a collection thereof, is the only thing that moves between the DomainObject and the DataProvider. I can then enforce via my interface what datastruct I should be receiving. This is not a silver bullet but I have found it to work well (Makes things like caching and unit testing quite easy)

I hope this hasn't confused the issue.